# How to find index in horizontal line in rectangle?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a draw by canvas like this picture:

[Click here to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCxxY.png)

I have index of horizontal rectangle (a1, a3, a5, a8, a10...) and vertical rectangle (a2, a4, a6, a7...). When touch a1, it show (1, 2), a3 show (2, 3)... The prolem is when i touch a8, it show (4, 5) (while correct should be 5, 6) and number 15 is the same(show (7, 8)), it should be show (9, 10). Here is my code

```
public Integer getIndex(int x, int y){
        int count_horizontal = 0;
        int count_vertical = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < Lines.size(); i++) {
            Lines line = Lines.get(i);
            if(line.horizontal) {
                count_horizontal ++;
                if(x >= line.x && x <= line.x + line_length &&
                        y >= line.y && y <= line.y) {
                    return count_horizontal;
                }
            } else {
                count_vertical++;
                if(x >= line.x && x <= line.x &&
                        y >= line.y && y <= line.y) {
                    return count_vertical;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Thank you very much!
Ps: Sorry for my english.

Comment: i don't really understand how the code relates to the question. It will return a single number, but you mention a pair. Some advice though: if i had to guess, it is because in the else, you have `y >= line.y && y <= line.y` and not `y >= line.y && y <= line.y + line_length`

Comment: @thinkgruen function getIndex is get coordinates x of horizontal rectangle. Example: getIndex(motionEvent.a, motionEvent.b) will get a index x.
 So if u see in a picture, when i touch a8, it show (4, 5) instead of (5, 6). Index x is wrong.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? was it fixed? because you need to be pixel perfect with your code - i guess it makes sense to always add the line.length for the upper bound in the checks? then the two `if` conditions are the same and can be merged

Comment: `y >= line.y && y <= line.y` would be `y == line.y` - i think if you intend this, you can simplify. if you don't, make sure the bounds are different.

Comment: @thinkgruen I added as you wanted but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that some of your tests are pixel-perfect. I think what you're looking for is something like this

```
public Integer getIndex(int x, int y){
        int count_horizontal = 0;
        int count_vertical = 0;
        for(Line line: Lines) { // consider lower-case lines for readability
          if(x >= line.x && x <= line.x + line_length &&
              y >= line.y && y <= line.y + line_length) { //consider making this a seperate isWithinBounds(line, x, y) method
            if (line.horizontal) {
              count_horizontal++;
            } else {
              count_vertical++;
            }
          }
        return null; // or 0 maybe?
    }
```

One thing I noticed that there is no separate line length for x and y, so it's more squares than rectangles?

Comment: Thank for your solution, but it didn't work. The index is null :(

Comment: yeah, this is again due to the pixel-perfect nature. let me return to and older revision then, now I think I understood it. Another thing is: are the lines in the correct order?

Comment: i think "if" is not a problem need to fix. when i touch "a8", the index show (4, 5) instead of (5, 6), so I think there's something wrong with the "a7"

Comment: Do any of the vertical rectangles work? You only mentioned the first horizontal ones. Can you also say how you use the index to get to (4,5) or (5,6)? Since it is the fourth horizontal line, it should return 4, no?

Comment: both a1 and a2 will return 1, so I'm not sure how this will work? maybe you can have a single counter and then say that a8 is in fact the eighth rectangle overall, not the fourth rectangle horizontally? then it is not ambiguous anymore.